# How to make search button enabled when pressed on enter when submit button is enabled using angular8

Tags: angular

i have a requirement where in when i fill some data into fields submit button will be enabled and keytab enter must hit the search button.
I have tried using hostListener event in one directive and tried to fetch that here on keytab enter, but it didnt work.
Any help appreciated.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hinjtr?file=src/app/app.component.html)

HTML:

```
<form>
<div class="modal rightside fade" id="agentAdvancedSearch" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true">
</form>
```

I tried giving the directive inside this div but it didnt detect

Comment: Please explain "keytab enter must hit the search button"

Comment: i mean when i press on enter in the keyboard, if the search button is enabled, then it must hit search button and close the popup opened in right hand side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle form submits on the `<form>` instead of the `<button>`. This will handle the button click and an "enter" key press.

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

You can use either `(ngSubmit)` or `(submit)`. There are subtle differences between the two of them, out of scope for this answer.

Comment: so with the implementation i have done is wrong? i need to call button inside <form> ?

Comment: Here they wanted template driven approach i used the way i implemented, thanks il check

Comment: The only thing that's wrong with your implementation is that you have `<button type="button">`. Remove that, and it will work

Comment: ya i will check

Comment: By that, I mean remove `type="button"`. It is implicitly `type="submit"`

Comment: i tried this in demo, it worked but couldnt make it work in application

Comment: So you're saying my answer does work or doesn't work? If you can recreate your problem in a stackblitz, I will look at it.

Comment: in application it didnt worked because i have used <form #loginForm="ngForm"> is that because of this?

Comment: no your answer is correct and it worked for me with my demo, now i recreated my demo, please have a look

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hinjtr?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Your problem is that you have set `data-dismiss="modal"` on your submit button. You are asking it to perform too many actions. I've just realised you're using jQuery. This is why you don't use jQuery in Angular - it becomes a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: The solution to how you dismiss the modal after submit is out of scope of this answer. I have answered your initial question. You now have a new problem that you need to work out how to fix.

Comment: yes i undestand, but thanks for response, i will vote answer because it helped me to find the root cause of my issue

Comment: Sorry, the issue is with the form i have used and not the data-dismiss"modal", if i remove the <form #loginForm="ngForm"> and use only <form> it works even with data-dismiss="modal"

Comment: have any other suggestion for this

Comment: The issue is with `data-dismiss="modal"`. If you remove that from the button and set the rest of the form up as I suggest, you can submit the form with button click of enter key. Obviously the modal doesn't get dismissed though. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2xzjqk

Comment: I would seriously suggest looking into using alternatives to jQuery. I use ng-bootstrap. ngx-bootstrap is also popular. There are several other libraries too.