# how to toggle the row using angular8

Tags: javascript, angular

i have multiple rows, if i open one row then i will not be able to toggle it, i mean it wont be closed unless the other row is clicked for viewing the inside data.
I must be able to toggle rows if i have not done anychanges to form, incase if i have made changes to that form, it must show me a confirmation message as it is showing currently.

DEMO:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kvm8a1?file=src/app/app.component.html)

TS:

```
 editEo(eo,index) {

      if(this.eoInfoForm.dirty) {

        this.confirmationDialogService.confirm('Please confirm..', 'Do you really want to save changes ?')
    .then((confirmed) => {
         let openedIndex = this.eoList.findIndex(obj => obj.OpenCloseStatus === true);
        confirmed ? this.OpenCloseEvent(eo,openedIndex):this.OpenCloseEvent(eo,index);
      if(confirmed){
        console.log("works")
      }
    })
    .catch(() => console.log('User dismissed the dialog (e.g., by using ESC, clicking the cross icon, or clicking outside the dialog)'));

  }else {
          //  this.eoDetailsList = previous; 
           eo.isCollapse = !eo.isCollapse
           this.OpenCloseEvent(eo,index);
          }
  }
```

HTML:

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="editEo(eo,i)" class="accordion-toggle">+ </a>
```

Comment: How many questions do you ask on here?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the line:

```
this.eoList[objIndex]['OpenCloseStatus'] = true;
```

with:

```
this.eoList[objIndex]['OpenCloseStatus'] = !this.eoList[objIndex]['OpenCloseStatus'];
```

Comment: Thanks for response, i hope it works i checked with demo it worked, i will check in my application.

Comment: anyidea about this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736463/how-to-make-search-button-enabled-when-pressed-on-enter-when-submit-button-is-en